# launchd equivalent for Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, boot, cmd.exe, launchd

Using launchd on OS X, I can make commands/programs run at boot with launchctl in the CLI, so for example:
`launchctl submit -l someName touch /usr/local/someFile`
Would create `someFile` in `/usr/local` when booting.

How can I achieve this on Windows? What can I do in the `cmd` to make Windows run certain commands when booting?

I would like to run some command when a certain user logs in.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Run a program during startup? Before a user login? During a user login?

Comment: @DavidPostill Preferably run some command when a certain user logs in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How do I run some command when a certain user logs in?

You can use the Task Scheduler to create a task that is triggered by a Kernel-Power log event that indicates "Sleep":

1. Run "Task Scheduler".
2. Select "Task Scheduler Library
3. Click menu "Action" > "Create Task"
4. Select "General" and give the task a "Name" and Description"
5. Select "Triggers" and click "New"

   - Set "Begin the Task" to "At log on"
   - Select "Specific user"
   - Press "Change User" and choose your "certain user"
   - Click "OK"

   [image]
6. Select "Actions" and click "New"

   - Set "Program/script" to a script of your choice
   - Click "OK"

   [image]

Comment: Is there a way to do exactly this with a CLI instead of the UI?

Comment: @Zocker3333 Link?

Answer (score 2):

Windows has a multitude of places where applications or commands can run on startup.

There's folders, registry entries etc. there are so many places that [msconfig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSConfig) has a Startup tab to try to show you some of them in one place.

You mention in the comment you want to have something start when a certain user logs in... and to save messing around with the registry then I would suggest creating a shortcut in the path:

```
C:\Users\<<Username>>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

This will vary depending on what version of Windows you are using. The folder you are looking for is the "startup folder" though for that user irrespective of Windows version.

If you wanted to do this from the command line then you could pipe your command into a batch file for instance or even use the Windows registry command line tools to add an entry to the registry's "Hive Key Current User" (HKCU) under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\